# Creating a grid in mapinfo

Tags: grid, mapinfo

i Need help in mapinfo. We are doing Raster based GIS and cartographic modelling.
I need to create a 100mX100m grid in mapinfo, but i'm not sure what extents i have to set for going further. 
Object type: Closed Regions
Smoothness: 0
Spacing Between lines is 100 meters, 
and projection set to British coordiante system..
please help me to make the grid.

Comment: What are your attempts so far? We'll be glad to help if we see some efforts from your side. we're not here to deliver code to you.

Comment: I am just starting the project. it will be started from a grid..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the 'Grid Maker' tool supplied with MapInfo based on the parameters you specified in your question. The extents are simply the minimum and maximum coordinates of the area you want covered by the grid. When you draw the rectangular area for your grid, these values are auto populated based on the rectangle you have drawn. If you want to manually adjust or change that area then you can do so by changing those values. So, let's say you want a grid which covers the area between `0,0` and `10,10` you would set your extents as:

North: 10
South: 0
East: 10
West: 0

Comment: I want to Set the extents of the Grid to coordinates which will cover the landmass of the
Isle of Wight.